# Deleting worksheet row based on value tied to a table

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row, listobject, excel-tables

I have a worksheet with two tables on it located starting in column B. In Column A I have a COUNTA formula that is tied to a delete blank rows button. My code works great to delete the table row but i need it to delete the entire worksheet row so that it also deletes the formula in column A instead of it continuously shifting down as rows are added or deleted.

The trouble is that I have two tables on the sheet so I need the deletion row action to refer only to the Local_1 table and the loop to stop when it reaches the end of that table.

Any suggestions on how to delete the entire row and not just the table row?

```
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=pswStr
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Local_1")
For i = .ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(0) <= 0 Then
            .ListRows(i).Delete                
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: `Cells()` is 1-based, so `If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1) = 0 Then`

Answer (score 1):

## List Entire Row

To not cramp your style, just replace

```
If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(0) <= 0 Then
    .ListRows(i).Delete                
End If
```

with

```
If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1) <= 0 Then 'as Tim Williams mentioned
    '.ListRows(i).Delete
    ActiveSheet.Rows(Range(.DataBodyRange.Address).Row + i - 1).Delete
End If
```

But (to cramp your style) I would strongly suggest you use (declare) variables like this:

```
Sub ListEntireRow()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim oWs As Worksheet
  Dim oList As ListObject

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set oWs = ActiveSheet
  Set oList = oWs.ListObjects("Local_1")

  oWs.Unprotect Password:=pswStr
  Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

  With oList
    For i = .ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
      If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1) <= 0 Then
'        .ListRows(i).Delete
        oWs.Rows(Range(.DataBodyRange.Address).Row + i - 1).Delete
      End If
    Next i
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Now you have the Intellisense for the Worksheet (oWs) and the ListObject (oList) working for you i.e. you can see their properties and methods.

Comment: Once I changed `If .ListRows(i).Range.Cells(1) <= 0` Then to `Cells(0)` to refer to my formula outside of the table in column A this worked perfectly. Thanks.